# telegram bot api - send additional data with replay keyboard

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm working on [telegram bot api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) and I send`ReplayKeyboard` with my message text to user. When a user click on a button, telegram sends a post with below structure to my webhook. Here is json structure of post:

```
{
    "update_id": *******,
    "message": {
        "message_id": ***,
        "from": {
            "id": *****,
            "is_bot": false,
            "first_name": "*****",
            "username": "******",
            "language_code": "en-US"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": *****,
            "first_name": "******",
            "username": "*****",
            "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1518716587,
        "text": "Button Text"
    }
}
```

My problem is **telegram does not accept any additional data for replay keyboard button.** So, I have to check `message.text` with **string** and this is not a good practice. For example if the button has emoji, the emoji code must be in the check. Also, I have different menu type and I need to find out type of clicked button, **but I have just text of the button**. So I need to assign **id** and **type** to each button. But I don't know how can I do it.

Here is the post data that my bots sends to user:

```
$keyboard = array(
        'resize_keyboard' => true,
        'keyboard' => array(
            array(
                array(
                   "text" => "Button Text"
                   //There is not any `id` or `type`,...
                )
            )
        )
    );

$post_fields = array(
    'chat_id' => **********
    'text' => ************,
    'reply_markup' => json_encode($keyboard)
);
```

**Note:** I don't want to **InlineKeyboard** and I need to use **RelplayKeyboard**.

If it's not possible, is there any alternative way? For example put additional data in button text and hide it from user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to save each user **stat**, so you can elect suitable reaction to similar text of button.

Also note that **emoji** is not horrible! and you don't need emoji code!
You just need to compare text that include emoji with a predefined string:

```
if('راهنما '===$receivedText)
    doSomeMagic();
```